# OpenCV code in PyCharm: Process finished with exit code 0

Tags: python, opencv

The program is saying Process finished with exit code 0 but i am not getting any output. I am using Python version 2.7 and the program's job is to detect free parking slots in a car park. It also has pedestrian detection.  Any help will be very much appreciated please i badly need this code to work. Thanks

Here is the link to the source code, along with a video link of how it works
https://github.com/ankit1khare/ComputerVision

DESIRED OUTPUT: The program should open the input video and draw the parking overlay on top of the video.

Here are the codes for the main program

```
import yaml
import numpy as np
import cv2

# path references

fn = "Khare_testvideo_01.mp4" #3
#fn = "datasets\parkinglot_1_720p.mp4"
#fn = "datasets\street_high_360p.mp4"
fn_yaml = "Khare_yml_01.yml"
fn_out =  "Khare_outputvideo_01.avi"
cascade_src = 'Khare_classifier_02.xml'
car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_src)
global_str = "Last change at: "
change_pos = 0.00
dict =  {
        'text_overlay': True,
        'parking_overlay': True,
        'parking_id_overlay': True,
        'parking_detection': True,
        'motion_detection': True,
        'pedestrian_detection': False, # takes a lot of processing power
        'min_area_motion_contour': 500, # area given to detect motion
        'park_laplacian_th': 2.8,
        'park_sec_to_wait': 1, # 4   wait time for changing the status of a region
        'start_frame': 0, # begin frame from specific frame number
        'show_ids': True, # shows id on each region
        'classifier_used': True,
        'save_video': True
        }

# Set from video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(fn)

print("video found")

video_info = {  'fps':    cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS),
                'width':  int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)*0.6),
                'height': int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)*0.6),
                'fourcc': cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC),
                'num_of_frames': int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))}

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, dict['start_frame']) # jump to frame number specified

def run_classifier(img, id):
    # gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.1, 1)
    if cars == ():

        return False

    else:
        # parking_status[id] = False

        return True


# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
if dict['save_video']:
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D') # options: ('P','I','M','1'), ('D','I','V','X'), ('M','J','P','G'), ('X','V','I','D')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(fn_out, -1, 25.0,(video_info['width'], video_info['height']))

    print("save video -- out  w * H")

# initialize the HOG descriptor/person detector. Take a lot of processing power.
if dict['pedestrian_detection']:
    hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
    hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())

    # Use Background subtraction
if dict['motion_detection']:
    fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=300, varThreshold=16, detectShadows=True)

# Read YAML data (parking space polygons)
with open(fn_yaml, 'r') as stream:
    parking_data = yaml.load(stream)
parking_contours = []
parking_bounding_rects = []
parking_mask = []
parking_data_motion = []
if parking_data != None:
    for park in parking_data:
        points = np.array(park['points'])
        rect = cv2.boundingRect(points)
        points_shifted = points.copy()
        points_shifted[:, 0] = points[:, 0] - rect[0] # shift contour to region of interest
        points_shifted[:, 1] = points[:, 1] - rect[1]
        parking_contours.append(points)
        parking_bounding_rects.append(rect)
        mask = cv2.drawContours(np.zeros((rect[3], rect[2]), dtype=np.uint8), [points_shifted], contourIdx=-1,
                                    color = 255, thickness=-1, lineType=cv2.LINE_8)
        mask = mask == 255
        parking_mask.append(mask)

kernel_erode = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3)) # morphological kernel
kernel_dilate = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(5,19))
if parking_data != None:
    parking_status = [False]*len(parking_data)
    parking_buffer = [None]*len(parking_data)
# bw = ()
def print_parkIDs(park, coor_points, frame_rev):
    moments = cv2.moments(coor_points)
    centroid = (int(moments['m10']/moments['m00'])-3, int(moments['m01']/moments['m00'])+3)
    # putting numbers on marked regions
    cv2.putText(frame_rev, str(park['id']), (centroid[0]+1, centroid[1]+1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(frame_rev, str(park['id']), (centroid[0]-1, centroid[1]-1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(frame_rev, str(park['id']), (centroid[0]+1, centroid[1]-1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(frame_rev, str(park['id']), (centroid[0]-1, centroid[1]+1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(frame_rev, str(park['id']), centroid, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    video_cur_pos = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) / 1000.0 # Current position of the video file in seconds
    video_cur_frame = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) # Index of the frame to be decoded/captured next
    ret, frame_initial = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        frame = cv2.resize(frame_initial, None, fx=0.6, fy=0.6)
    if ret == False:
        print("Video ended")
        break

    # Background Subtraction
    frame_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame.copy(), (5,5), 3)
    # frame_blur = frame_blur[150:1000, 100:1800]
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame_blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frame_out = frame.copy()

    # Drawing the Overlay. Text overlay at the left corner of screen
    if dict['text_overlay']:
        str_on_frame = "%d/%d" % (video_cur_frame, video_info['num_of_frames'])
        cv2.putText(frame_out, str_on_frame, (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.8, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.putText(frame_out,global_str + str(round(change_pos, 2)) + 'sec', (5, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.8, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

    # motion detection for all objects
    if dict['motion_detection']:
        # frame_blur = frame_blur[380:420, 240:470]
        # cv2.imshow('dss', frame_blur)
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame_blur)
        bw = np.uint8(fgmask==255)*255
        bw = cv2.erode(bw, kernel_erode, iterations=1)
        bw = cv2.dilate(bw, kernel_dilate, iterations=1)
        # cv2.imshow('dss',bw)
        # cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % co, bw)
        (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(bw.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        # loop over the contours
        for c in cnts:
            # print(cv2.contourArea(c))
            # if the contour is too small, we ignore it
            if cv2.contourArea(c) < dict['min_area_motion_contour']:
                continue
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            cv2.rectangle(frame_out, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 1)

    # detecting cars and vacant spaces
    if dict['parking_detection']:
        for ind, park in enumerate(parking_data):
            points = np.array(park['points'])
            rect = parking_bounding_rects[ind]
            roi_gray = frame_gray[rect[1]:(rect[1]+rect[3]), rect[0]:(rect[0]+rect[2])] # crop roi for faster calcluation

            laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(roi_gray, cv2.CV_64F)
            # cv2.imshow('oir', laplacian)
            points[:, 0] = points[:, 0] - rect[0] # shift contour to roi
            points[:, 1] = points[:, 1] - rect[1]
            delta = np.mean(np.abs(laplacian * parking_mask[ind]))
            # if(delta<2.5):
                # print("ind, del", ind, delta)
            status = delta < dict['park_laplacian_th']
            # If detected a change in parking status, save the current time
            if status != parking_status[ind] and parking_buffer[ind]==None:
                parking_buffer[ind] = video_cur_pos
                change_pos = video_cur_pos
                # print("state ", ind,delta)
                # applying classifier in case a change is detected in the status of area
                # if dict['classifier_used']:
                #     classifier_result = run_classifier(roi_gray)
                #     if classifier_result:
                #         print(classifier_result)
            # If status is still different than the one saved and counter is open
            elif status != parking_status[ind] and parking_buffer[ind] != None:
                if video_cur_pos - parking_buffer[ind] > dict['park_sec_to_wait']:
                    parking_status[ind] = status
                    parking_buffer[ind] = None
            # If status is still same and counter is open
            elif status == parking_status[ind] and parking_buffer[ind] != None:
                parking_buffer[ind] = None

    # changing the color on the basis on status change occured in the above section and putting numbers on areas
    if dict['parking_overlay']:
        for ind, park in enumerate(parking_data):
            points = np.array(park['points'])
            if parking_status[ind]:
                color = (0, 255, 0)
                rect = parking_bounding_rects[ind]
                roi_gray_ov = frame_gray[rect[1]:(rect[1] + rect[3]),
                               rect[0]:(rect[0] + rect[2])]  # crop roi for faster calcluation
                res = run_classifier(roi_gray_ov, ind)
                if res:
                    parking_data_motion.append(parking_data[ind])
                    # del parking_data[ind]
                    color = (0, 0, 255)
            else:
                color = (0, 0, 255)

            cv2.drawContours(frame_out, [points], contourIdx=-1,
                                 color=color, thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_8)
            if dict['show_ids']:
                    print_parkIDs(park, points, frame_out)



    if parking_data_motion != []:
        for index, park_coord in enumerate(parking_data_motion):
            points = np.array(park_coord['points'])
            color = (0, 0, 255)
            recta = parking_bounding_rects[ind]
            roi_gray1 = frame_gray[recta[1]:(recta[1] + recta[3]),
                            recta[0]:(recta[0] + recta[2])]  # crop roi for faster calcluation
            # laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(roi_gray, cv2.CV_64F)
            # delta2 = np.mean(np.abs(laplacian * parking_mask[ind]))
            # state = delta2<1
            # classifier_result = run_classifier(roi_gray1, index)
            # cv2.imshow('dsd', roi_gray1)
            fgbg1 = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=300, varThreshold=16, detectShadows=True)
            roi_gray1_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(roi_gray1.copy(), (5, 5), 3)
            # cv2.imshow('sd', roi_gray1_blur)
            fgmask1 = fgbg1.apply(roi_gray1_blur)
            bw1 = np.uint8(fgmask1 == 255) * 255
            bw1 = cv2.erode(bw1, kernel_erode, iterations=1)
            bw1 = cv2.dilate(bw1, kernel_dilate, iterations=1)
            # cv2.imshow('sd', bw1)
            # cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % co, bw)
            (_, cnts1, _) = cv2.findContours(bw1.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            # loop over the contours
            for c in cnts1:
                print(cv2.contourArea(c))
                # if the contour is too small, we ignore it
                if cv2.contourArea(c) < 4:
                    continue
                (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                classifier_result1 = run_classifier(roi_gray1, index)
                if classifier_result1:
                # print(classifier_result)
                    color = (0, 0, 255)  # Red again if car found by classifier
                else:
                    color = (0,255, 0)
            classifier_result1 = run_classifier(roi_gray1, index)
            if classifier_result1:
                # print(classifier_result)
                color = (0, 0, 255)  # Red again if car found by classifier
            else:
                color = (0, 255, 0)
            cv2.drawContours(frame_out, [points], contourIdx=-1,
                                 color=color, thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_8)

    if dict['pedestrian_detection']:
        # detect people in the image. Slows down the program, requires high GPU speed
        (rects, weights) = hog.detectMultiScale(frame, winStride=(4, 4), padding=(8, 8), scale=1.05)
        # draw the  bounding boxes
        for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
            cv2.rectangle(frame_out, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    # write the output frames
    if dict['save_video']:
        #if video_cur_frame % 35 == 0: # take every 30 frames
            out.write(frame_out)

    # Display video
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame_out)
    # cv2.imshow('background mask', bw)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k == ord('q'):
        break
    elif k == ord('c'):
        cv2.imwrite('frame%d.jpg' % video_cur_frame, frame_out)
    elif k == ord('j'):
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, video_cur_frame+1000) # jump 1000 frames
    elif k == ord('u'):
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, video_cur_frame + 500)  # jump 500 frames
    if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:
        break

cv2.waitKey(0)
cap.release()
if dict['save_video']: out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Which file are you running? Please post your code here instead of the link.

Comment: What part of the code are you expecting an output from ? Could you post this part instead of a link. What output are you expecting ? Have you tried to debug it ?

Comment: Yes i tried debugging it and the program is not being able to read the initial video

while(cap.isOpened()):  The "cap" is returning false which means its not reading the video. The program is not executing all the functions that are inside the while loop.  I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

change your these lines

```
`if dict['save_video']:
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D') # options: ('P','I','M','1'), ('D','I','V','X'), ('M','J','P','G'), ('X','V','I','D')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(fn_out, -1, 25.0,(video_info['width'], video_info['height']))`
```

to

```
`if dict['save_video']:
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID') # options: ('P','I','M','1'), ('D','I','V','X'), ('M','J','P','G'), ('X','V','I','D')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(fn_out, fourcc, 25.0,(video_info['width'], video_info['height']))`
```

and try again

Also put your functions/methods definitions to the top of the code.